# ValueError: X has 1 features, but SVC is expecting 3 features as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to create a stock price predictor *(not to actually use it to invest don't worry)* using Keras and sklearn, which grabs any of the time series from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/szrlee/stock-time-series-20050101-to-20171231) and checks the "Close". It then takes a rolling time window of a particular length and predicts the directional accuracy, up (1) or down (0).

While trying to run the code below, the following error came up:

```
File "...", line 71, in test
    y_pred = self.model.predict(self.X_test)
ValueError: X has 1 features, but SVC is expecting 3 features as input.
```

Can someone guide me on what could possibly be the issue? What are the features that SVC is expecting that I may be missing?

**CODE: Model.py**

`create_features` checks if market is lower or higher according to rolling time window, and sets X and y:

```
#window_size = the set size of the rolling time window

def create_features(data, window_size):
    X = []
    y = []

    for i in range(0, len(data.index) - window_size):
        temp = [data.iloc[i + j]['Close'] for j in range(0, window_size)]
        avg = sum(temp) / len(temp)

        X.append(temp)
        y.append(0 if data.iloc[i + window_size]['Close'] < avg else 1)

    return X, y
```

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, market: Market, training_percent: float, window_size: int):
        self.model = SVC(C=10, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf')

        X, y = create_features(market.data, window_size)
        self.X_train, self.y_train, self.X_test, self.y_test = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=False, stratify=None, train_size=training_percent)

        self.X_train = np.array(self.X_train)
        self.y_train = np.array(self.y_test)

        #self.X_test = np.array(self.X_test).reshape(-1, 1)

    def train(self):
        self.model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

    def test(self):
        y_pred = self.model.predict(self.X_test) #THE COMPLAINING LINE

        y_pred = [0 if i < 0.5 else 1 for i in y_pred]
        tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(self.y_test, y_pred, labels=[0, 1]).ravel()
        print(tn, fp, fn, tp)
        print("Accuracy:", (tn + fp) / (tn + fp + fn + tp))

    def predict(self, input_array):
        return self.model.predict(input_array)
```

**The above are called as:**

```
model_test = Model(markets[m], training_testing[j], window_size[i])
model_test.train()
model_test.test()
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `np.shape(X_test)`?

Comment: @user2246849 np.reshape() was used to solve another issue where "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead". The solution to add "reshape" is suggested in the error itself "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: Sorry, I meant whats the shape of X_test, so the output of the command I wrote above.

Comment: @user2246849 My bad, the output is "(1508, 1)"

Comment: And this is with or without the `reshape(-1, 1)`? Can you do the same with `X_train`, i.e. `np.shape(X_train)`?

Comment: @user2246849 Without ```.reshape(-1, 1)```, it's ```(1508,)```. The ```(1508, 1)``` was with the reshape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you are getting the output of `train_test_split`. As the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) states, you should get the split datasets in order:

```
# Notice the order of the unpacking.
self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=False, stratify=None, train_size=training_percent)
```

Hence, the testing dataset was of different shape because it was actually the training labels. You will not need the `.reshape` either.

Also, not sure you want to do this:

```
# Assigning y_test to y_train.
self.y_train = np.array(self.y_test)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was taking the order from old notes rather than the documentation, big mistake! With regards to the second point, that was an error from my end while removing the unnecessary code for posting.

Comment: Thank you! This mis-ordering was causing so many unnecessary problems in my assignment.